# Selecting values from pandas rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

Hello I want to make a for loop that will get all the values from each row and dump it into a list.
I want the list to overwrite on the same variable.

I made something like this but there is now way i can figure out how to print or append only row values.

```
rows_count = len(df.index)

for i in range(rows_count):
    extracted_row = df.iloc[[0]]
    print(extracted_row)
    if i == 1:
        break
```

I tried to make a for loop over `extracted_row` but it does not work.

This is the result I am getting but i'd like it to be just a list of values

Instead of this:
[image]

I'd like to get this:

```
[1,28,2,208,...0,6,4]
```

Comment: Then do `extracted_row.values` to get numpy array and `extracted_row.values.tolist()` to get Python list

Comment: @ThePyGuy Could you show me a snippet of code? I tried to do it myself but i get all sort of errors :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach the expected output using `values` :

```py
rows_count = len(df.index)

for i in range(rows_count):
    extracted_row = df.iloc[[i]].values[0].tolist()
    print(extracted_row)
    if i == 1:
        break
```

Output :

```
[-0.4638010118887267, 0.8128665595646368, 0.10555011868229829, -1.0352554514123276]
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want, but I want the list to be overwritten by values from next row. With`df.iloc[[0]]` and `.values[0]` i get 1st row for every iteration.

Comment: Nevermind. I managed to do it by putting `i` in `df.iloc[[i]]`

Comment: I updated my answer to fit with you last comment.